# Phone socket replacement

Tags: telephone

I have a faulty phone wall socket which I think needs replacing. I am not very familiar with this type of technology so I don't know what I need. I have attached a pic of the one I have now. The problem is that the wire going into it doesn't click in to place, it sort of comes back out naturally. It was held in by a big wooden speaker but that no longer seems to work. I can get a dial tone if I push it in with all my force but that's not really a suitable solution. Any help is much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Where in the world are you?
And can you photo the cord that plugged in?  It is possible that the latch on the cord broke off, and you need to replace the cord, not the jack.

Comment: Yes, where are you on this planet?

Comment: That's a BT phone Jack with a British Telecom logo,  so somewhere in the British isles is a fair bet.

Comment: we use those in NZ too, but I think the wiring practice mat be different here.

Comment: @DaveM I am in the UK (England). I tried many different wired going into it. All of them worked when held in place by my hand. This makes me think it's the socket?

I'm confused by all the wires and shit. I unscrewed the face plate leaving the internal wires alone, plugged my telephone wire into the face plate and picked up my phone to hear if there was a dial tone. There was when I held the wire into the wall with my hand. I did this because I thought there might be something behind the face plate pushing against the cable therefore pushing it out but there  was no evidence of this.

Comment: We do have another of these upstairs which is what I'm using now with the phone and broadband hub plugged in and working perfectly. It's just unsuitable place for landline to be in. 

I couldn't really see where any if the internal wiring goes on the face plate as it was so tight against the wall. I thought I'd be able to just unscrew the wires and use the face plate from upstairs. There's no way I can get a screwdriver in there lol I can't even see in there.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your only socket it should be a master and replaceable with an Openreach Linebox.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbfHMsP6IsE

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NTE5C/254283763063

Note - if you do want Openreach to replace it for you, you'll have to book that through your phone provider (whether that's BT, Talktalk, Sky, Plusnet etc) as Openreach don't deal with consumers.

If it's an extension socket, just replace it with a LJU 2/3A.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/BT-Socket-LJU2-3A-/221531118698

For that you will need an IDC insertion tool (included by that seller)

Details on UK telephone wiring (and how to tell the difference between master and extension sockets)
http://www.rob-r.co.uk/other/UKphonecatwiring.htm

Comment: I'm with EE broadband but I was with BT for like 20 something years before I switched. I might be looking to switch again soon. Would the socket be changed anyway if they come to install fibre optic?

Comment: No, because Fibre to the cabinet (FTTC or Superfast) is customer-installed by you plugging in the modem into the phone socket. Only if you get Fibre to the Home (FTTH or Ultrafast) will you get an engineer visit, and they'll do the fibre installation and not necessarily touch the copper wire.

Answer (score 0):

Jusdging by the circle-T logo I think that's a master socket, in which case it's British Telecoms problem not yours. call BT and tell them your phone socket is malfunctioning.  they'll send out a technician to replace it for you.